Deleted accidentally the admin of the IPA server
I deleted from the GUI the admin user on ipa. I'm trying to restore it by assigning admin permissions to some other ipa users but i'm getting back this error:
Failed members:
member user: superuser: Insufficient access: Insufficient 'write' privilege to the 'member' attribute of entry 'cn=admins,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=dc,dc=dc,dc=dc,dc=dc,dc=com'.
Would it be more optimal to reinstall the ipa-server or are they any other solutions?

If you do not have a drive image to restore, then reinstallation seems the only practical way to get a working system.
